# Aggregation of correlated variables

Tags: time-series, aggregation, copula

I've been trying to aggregate *correlated* time series, by using Alexander's proposal that you can see here: http://bit.ly/1hIPwiI.

Her proposal to find a random variable $Y=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$, where each $X_i$ represents a stochastic process, is based on solving an integral of dimension $N-1$. The problem that I see is that the integral must be solved by iterative methods (I use Monte Carlo) when the dimension is high. Even so, when $N>5$ my results are really disappointing; with large errors in some point estimates.

The question that I ask here is, Is there any other method to solve the problem of portfolio aggregation (summation of random variables) when the variables are correlated? In other words, if I have the marginal distributions of $X_1, \ldots, X_N$, how can I find the distribution of$Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you expect some fast analytical method. Unfortunately, there is no such thing for the general problem deriving the full distribution of $Y=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$. The most generic answer to this problem is indeed to use Monte-Carlo simulations, and if the accuracy is an issue for you, then you should think about using some variance reduction techniques. As always when dealing with copulas, it depends on the particular problem you have at hand. In particular, it depends on:

1. **The copula function and the marginals**

   - Gaussian copula with Gaussian marginals will give you a multivariate gaussian distribution, for which you will be able to determine the law of the sum, so you could hope for some analytical method.
   - Generally, if the random vector $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,\dots,X_N)^T$ has an elliptical distribution, then $Y=\mathbf{1}^T \mathbf{X}$, and again we can hope for something analytically tranctable.
   - Other configurations will be unlikely to lead you to anything analytical.
2. **What you want to do with $Y$**

   - if you really want to characterize the full distribution of $Y$, then that's ambitious...
   - if you are only interest in some "part of the distribution of $Y$" and want to apply some functional $\Psi$ to $Y$ to compute $\mathbb{E}[\Psi(Y)]$ - note that a lot of problems can be reduced to this - then some bespoke variance reduction techniques such as Importance Sampling may be available to you. See for example in the [Credit Risk literature](http://finmath.stanford.edu/seminars/documents/Glasserman_IS_CreditRisk.pdf)  or in the [Insurance literature](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.4291)

In any case, you will need to say more about the settings of your problem to see if there is something smarter to do than Crude Monte Carlo.